# How to run batch file early in windows boot process

Tags: windows-10, boot

I’m looking for ways that you can make windows run a batch file when it boots. I’d like to run the batch file each time the PC boots and as quickly as possible. I don’t want to wait for a user to log in.

Given that I have full admin access to the PC, what method can I use that will cause the batch file to run at the earliest possible moment in the boot process.

Comment: You need to create a Service for what you wish to do and then set the Service to run at startup before login. Numerous Services do that now on Windows workstations.

Comment: Would a basic scheduled task set to run "when the computer starts" do?

Comment: Thanks. I think both a service and a scheduled task are valid ways to start the batch file at startup. Any idea which would run first out of the two?

Comment: The process that runs Scheduled Tasks is itself a service, which begs the question in which order Windows services are started. Which you can research elsewhere. If you set your own service start to `system` it should run before the Task Scheduler service.